# How to make a luck mage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, class, conversion, open-legend

I have a player attempting to make a [Pathfinder Malefactor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/total-party-kill-games-classes/malefactor/) in Open Legend.

But I don't know which stat could reasonably be used to create bad luck. Are there any descriptions of uses for a stat, banes, or boons that could replicate bad luck with reflavoring?

I don't want any homebrew other than how I flavor the abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presence is an attribute that can be associated with luck as well, and used to inflict a demoralized to give out disadvantage (something that represents bad luck through flavoring).

Can also do Entropy as a good attribute to give out misfortune as well. Or even Attribute Sub II Presence > Entropy

I would also look at the [Barrier Boon](http://www.openlegendrpg.com/boons/barrier). Like Aura, it can affect allies who enter it as well, and has a choice of effects that could easily be reflavored (dust getting in the eyes = obscuring, tripping in the area to cause damage, etc etc).

Also, visiting the community site for Open Legend is a good way to get some answers.

Answer (score 2):

This will mostly be accomplished through use of creative flavor, but here are some examples to start with:

- The Aura of Misfortune will likely be represented by [the Aura boon](http://www.openlegendrpg.com/boons/aura) radiating [the Demoralized bane](http://www.openlegendrpg.com/banes/demoralized).  This will cause nearby creatures to suffer Disadvantage on action rolls (the exact radius and amount of Disadvantage will depend on the power level at which it is invoked).  Note, however, that this combination requires an Attribute score of at least 6, which means that it cannot be utilized at first level without spending all 6 initial feat points on the Boon Access feat.
- Even apart from the Aura, Demoralized will be a good choice of banes to represent bad luck.
- Entropy can invoke many banes, and it conceptually fits with the idea of stealing luck.

Comment: Using the core mechanic in combat allows the GM to inflict a bane of PL 3 or less on a failed attack roll - this could be used to inflict Knockdown, Slowed, Disarmed, Sickened, Nullify, etc. - all described as bad luck.